Which aircraft has the simplest folding wing mechanism?
From all the different folding wing mechanisms, which airplane has one of the simplest / easiest mechanisms?

I think this is my favourite folding wing mechanism: https://www.foldnfly.com/15.html#Spin-Plane

A single sweep with one huge hinge-pin (and leaking fuel tanks) was a characteristic of the F-111 (Aardvark). The B-1 and F-14 shared similar sweep wings. Now "sweep" may be something different than "fold" you are asking, but the sweep was fairly simple in concept.

Sweep is also valid answer. Now there are not many(only come to mind the ones you mentioned) or are there more? It seems folding is easier/simpler design than sweep.

@David C. Rankin This should be an answer. I'd vote for it.

Yes, just a bit confused by the "fold" term. The sweep and fold generally are done for different purposes. The sweep is done to alter the flight-envelope of the aircraft allowing for flight at slower speed for takeoff/landing. The "fold" is generally done for space saving during transport/storage like on a carrier. Arguably both fold, but just depends on what the questioner is looking for. The answer captures the simplest by far.

There are many planes with folding wing structures. Some like the F/A-18 fold a small part of the overall wing and similar is with the 777X
From what I got to know, the aircraft with the simplest folding structure (experimental and kit planes included), would be this Onex Kit plane by Sonex Aircraft
It has a really simple system,

The folding wing feature provides one handle this is pulled to release two spar pins, one in the main spar, one in the rear spar. With the pins released, the wing is simply folded by-hand into the up position. The wing fold handle has a spring loaded locking pin that keeps the wings locked for flight. The wing fold & unfold/lock process takes only about 30 seconds per wing!

This is a quote from their website which shows how simple the system is. It's not even electrical or hydraulic so I'm guessing it has to be the simplest.

This plane in flight

Wings folded with folding mechanism visible

Out of curiosity, is the handle inside the cockpit or on the wing?

Can you imagine if the handle was in the cockpit right next to the throttle :D perhaps there is some kind of mechanism that prevents the pins to be released during flight, like when the engine is on, or something like that.

If I were designing such a thing, I'd probably lean towards something like the wing loading forcing the pin into an immovable position, rather than making it depend on the engine. Make it physically impossible to move the wing while in flight.

F-18 folds almost about a third of the wing, lerx excluded.
